# How can i type a input value using typescript without receive the error message below?

Tags: typescript

i was creating a application with typescript and in certain moment he gives me the following error:
"Type 'HTMLElement' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLFormElement': acceptCharset, action, autocomplete, elements, and 12 more.ts(2740".
if i put htmlelement i cannot use length, if i put htmlformelement he writes that error above. What can i do?

follow the code below:

```
public addValues() {
        const inputValue: HTMLFormElement
        = document.getElementById('valor')!

        const inputNameValue: HTMLFormElement
        = document.getElementById('nome-valor')!

        if (inputValue?.length && inputNameValue?.length) {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById` is a function that returns a common denominator interface of `HTMLElement` as an id is an attribute that can be applied to any html elemnt. It isn't a generic function that you can tell it which element type you expect to be returned by it. `HTMLFormElement` element extends the `HTMLElement` interface and adds properties that are specific to a Form element.

To get rid of this error, you need to explicitly tell Typescript what type you are expecting to be selected. You would do that as follows:

```
const inputValue = document.getElementById('valor')! as HTMLFormElement;
const inputNameValue = document.getElementById('nome-valor')! as HTMLFormElement;
```

Comment: Or pass it as a generic type parameter.

Comment: @vr. Not sure what you mean: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/663b19fe4a7c4d4ddaa61aedadd28da06acd27b6/tests/cases/compiler/genericMethodOverspecialization.ts This method doesn't accept a generic type parameter.

Comment: Oh I thought you were using `querySelector`, but perhaps it should sometime in the future.